# Extension to serialize read-only properties

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, access-modifiers

I'm writing a simple extension that allow to serialize multi-dimensional arrays. Internally I'm using `XmlSerializer` for array items, but it doesn't work for read-only properties. So how can I serialize them in XML using `XmlSerializer` (or some another class like `DataContractSerializer`) without modifying classes to have these properties. I mean I have method `Serialize<T>(T obj)` and I would be able to serialize it for any `T`, even structs like `KeyValuePair<T,U>` with read-only properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`.

Using `DataContractSerializer`, you can serialize / deserialize `private` and even `readonly` fields / properties, however every field / property to serialize needs to be marked with the `DataMember` attribute, so it can't be used for arbitrary types, such as `KeyValuePair<K,V>`.

Other than doing it by hand using an XML API (such as Linq2Xml, for example) and reflection, you could look at [sharpserializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html) which seems to do exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm able to serialize multi-dim arrays, i just want to evade a situation, when serializer doesn't serialize read-only properties.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Editet answer.